# Conditional Probability equality

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Suppose $B$ and $C$ are independent event, then is it true that $$P[(A|B)|C)=P[A|(B\cap C)]$$
This looks to be true after some calculations using Bayes formula. But I did not get the exact equality. Any hints and ideas?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathsf P[(A\mid B)\mid C)]$ is not a well formed formula.   The mid bar is part of the conditional probability function; it is *not* a set operator on the events.   (There can only be one.) $$\mathsf P(\text{list of events}\mid \text{list of conditions})$$

However, both lists are conjunctive, if that's what you meant to ask.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\mid B, C) & = \mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)
\\[1ex] & = {\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)\over\mathsf P(B\mid C)} & = {\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)\over \mathsf P(B\cap C)}
\\[1ex] & = {\mathsf P(A, B\mid C)\over\mathsf P(B\mid C)} & = {\mathsf P(A,B,C)\over \mathsf P(B, C)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: hmm, so the comma means $\cap$?

Comment: In a conjunctive list, yes. @nerd